# How to save downloaded assets to disk on iOs or Android air project (AS3)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, file, download, save

I figured how to save txts etc but theres no way on earth I can save mp3s,jpgs, or zip files on my iPhones hard disk, and I really cannot understan why..

lets assume im doing the following:

```
var btAr:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); //initializing byte array
var snd:Sound = new mp3sound(); //this is an embeeded mp3 file !

snd.extract(btAr,int(mp3sound.length * 44.1) )  //extract the mp3 into a byte array
btAr.position = 0; 
var str:String = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath;  
appTempData = new File(str +"/\.\./tmp");    //temp folder of an iOs app

fr = new FileStream();
try
{
    fr.open(
        appTempData     //  appTempData or appCache or appData or userDocs
        .resolvePath("myCache.mp3"),FileMode.WRITE); 
    fr.writeBytes(btAr)
    fr.close(); 
}
catch(er:Error)
{
    trace("ERROR: "+er);
}
```

No errors, no nothing, I just get a blank mp3 file (0 kb).

My purpose is to download various files from an external server, and save them to my iPhones tmp directory... I don't even care about them being loaded at that point. I manage to download files in my iPhones memory but I cant seem to save them on my Iphones disk..!

Lights plz?

Comment: Right before `fr.writeBytes(btAr)`, add a `trace( btAr.length );`. My guess is not that you are saving incorrectly, but that you are saving an empty ByteArray.

Comment: You are correct Apocalyptic0n3 ! My byte array is indeed empty.. Question.. Is ByteArray the only format on which I can save a file? If so what is the right way to convert mp3s,jpgs to byte Array?

Comment: Problem solved... I'm using mp3sound.length instead of snd.length...! Noobish mistake..! Thank you guys for your replies....!

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 var outFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myCache.mp3");
 var outStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
 outStream.open(outFile, FileMode.WRITE);
 outStream.writeBytes(btAr);
 outStream.close();
```

It need to save in applicationStorageDirectory!

Comment: Not true, this is iOs environment we are working with.. I know for certain my directories are correct..! I've worked lots of times with those directories..! Still thanks!